# Nexus 4 - Failed to install Ubuntu Touch

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I have followed the steps on the Ubuntu website as it says, and it gets stuck halfway through 'phablet-flash -b'. What makes it worse i then when i try to put it into recovery, and run the code 'adb devices' it doesn't show any devices?

Any help please?

Comment: Can you paste the full output of what happens?

Answer (score 0):

To recover:

Put the device in 'Recovery Mode', and then run:

```
phablet-flash -d mako -b
```

---

***IF that fails, revert to factory / Android setup.***

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Look for: 'Restoring Android'

( *You may also need to put phone into 'Recovery Mode' for this to work.* )